# SwiftUI - ScrollView Data is Disappearing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a ScrollView that loops through data and passes it into a view. In the iOS simulator, the data persists and remains in the screen. But when using it on a device, the views load but disappear after a few seconds.

```swift
struct MessageThreadView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var messagesManager: MessagesManager
    let thread: MessageThread

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    ScrollViewReader { value in
                        ForEach(Array(messagesManager.messages.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, message in
                            ChatMessageBubble(message: message)
                        }.onAppear {
                            value.scrollTo(messagesManager.messages.last?.messageId, anchor: .center)
                        }
                    }
                }.id(UUID().uuidString)
            }
            MessageFieldView(threadUid: thread.uid)
                .environmentObject(messagesManager)
        }
            .task {
                print("Getting messages")
                messagesManager.getMessagesForThread(threadId: thread.uid)
            }
    }

}
```

I've avoided using a List because when using a List there's a border around it. I'm using a ScrollViewReader so I can scroll to the bottom of the messages when a conversation is opened.

And I had read on a previous question that adding .id then it resolves a caching issue. But this hasn't occurred for me.

Comment: Using `.id(UUID().uuidString)` is a very bad idea, except under certain circumstances. It guarantees that your scrollview will be completely rebuilt/rerendered on every render of the parent. Without a [mre], I'd vote for this being part of the problem.

Comment: Before adding the .id, this problem existed. So it's redundant, but I wanted to illustrate that I had tried this solution.

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: I've updated to include the whole view

Comment: That is not a [mre] -- can you make something that others can run to be able to reproduce the situation.

Comment: Apple places the `ScrollView` inside of the [`ScrollViewReader`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader)

Comment: @vacawama I didn't spot that, but I have changed and the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

I switched the MessagesManager class that held the data that was disappearing from an `@EnvironmentObject` to a `@StateObject` and that fixed the problem.